# How do I modify my search to view only closed questions?

Tags: support

I would like to be able to view closed questions. I recently found out that just because they are closed doesn't mean they are dead. It's one of the things I think probably frustrate users the most, or if not it frustrates me a bit, so I would like to take a gander as to how daunting a task it would be to apply first aid to good, yet malformed questions. How do I view only closed questions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put `closed:1` in the search box too, as described in [the Advanced Super Ninja Search Options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search).

Comment: Thank you, I want to pick this as the answer but I have to wait 5 minutes?? How do you get to that search page, I don't see a link for it anywhere, I'm sure it's under my nose but where lol EDIT: Got it, it's hidden in the FAQ

Comment: @Mallow You can also just hit Enter in the search box without typing anything to get there